# How to extract public key in proper format using openssl in php?

Tags: php, openssl, ssl-certificate, public-key

I have made many attempts using differnt ways, to extract public key in displayable format using openssl in php. 
E.g.

> print_r(openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_csr_get_public_key(\path to csr)));

```
var_dump(openssl_get_publickey(file_get_contents('\\path to cert')));
```

and many more. But all I can get is something like this:

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQClNami19DpcxlYAaZNxHV27r2V gDQbkZhiayaDfcwjYStRaU8Hk1yg76gfhgayssIa6Y7Cek4uH5fV PE6Nj/s9QAkcvpzZDJasdYmj8BGyVwVbRelToMNvXTc eNaH93Dm+OA4TE9yoQIDAQAB

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

How can I extract it in the format given below:

95 ae 9a 4e db f1 6d 15 55 9f 86 52 28 54 21 3f 
88 1b 21 81 2a 01 e3 35 dd 21 51 44 f4 18 bf 85 
fb f0 6a 9a 9c 15 7f 46 83 b8 1e 05 b7 b9 1a 
9d fd 58 0b fa 45 01 f2 3b 3b bc 1b f6 a3 20 7b 
96 3e f7 5d d6 c2 a7 56 29 02 94 ba 0c 29 da 51

Thank you.

Comment: What format is that hex dump?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure about the name of the format. But I got this by viewing certificate details from the browser.

Answer (score 5):

The public key listed by a browser is just a hexadecimal encoding of the modulus. Within the data structure returned by `openssl_pkey_get_details` this is represented by `n`. (If you're curious why, check out the [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) algorithm.) To get it in PHP just do:

```
$pkey_details = openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("test.pem")));
echo bin2hex($pkey_details["rsa"]["n"]);
```